# jQuery add class when link does not contain an image

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get jQuery to add a class to all external links, but only when the link is wrapped around text and not an image. I've used the :not selector and the code looks right to me but for some reason it's having the opposite effect and adding the class to images and not the text links.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks, here's my code…

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    // Add a css class to all external text links
    $('#main a:not(:has(img)').filter(function() {
        return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
    }).addClass("externalLink");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're missing a closing `)` in the selector, and the order of the nested pseudo-selectors matter, try reversing them: `:not(:has(img))` as opposed to `:has(:not(img))`

The amended code then looks like:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    // Add a css class to all external text links
    $('#main a:not(:has(img))').filter(function() {
        return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
    }).addClass("externalLink");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y5e8kxz5/

Comment: Perfect xec thanks a lot. I didn't see the missing closing bracket but it was the order of the selectors that was causing the issue. Thanks for your help, much appreciated :-)

Comment: @JamesPayne Glad to be of help :) I've made the same mistake myself before. In my case I ended up deciding that complex logic was better than a complex selector. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/y5e8kxz5/2/

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a syntax error (`not` parentheses are opening but not closing), and as far as i know you don't need to surround :has(img) with parentheses.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    // Add a css class to all external text links
    $('#main a:not:has(img)').filter(function() {
        return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
    }).addClass("externalLink");
});
```

Comment: I have tried it without the parentheses around the not but it doesn't work so I guess it does need them. Thanks for your help, much appreciated :-)

Comment: The `:has()` usually doesn't need parentheses around it, but you can't omit the parentheses for `:not()`, so in this case you need both sets.

Answer (score -1):

LIVE DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/don/0h56bjae/4/

---

You can use `each()` to check if the link has image and add class if yes. And use RegExp to check if the url is external or not.

```
var cp = new RegExp(location.host);

$('a').each(function() {
    if($(this).find("img").length > 0 && cp.test($(this).find('img').attr('src')) == false) {
        $(this).addClass('external-img');
    }
});
```

Comment: I believe the filter is to check if the link points to a different domain, hence the class `externalLink`.